# href with "javascript" doesn't work in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have page.html where there is following code:

```html
<iframe srcdoc="&lt;a href=&quot;javascript:console.log(1)&quot;&gt;test&lt;/a&gt;" sandbox="allow-same-origin || allow-scripts || allow-top-navigation || allow-popups"></iframe>
```

I allow scripts, top-navigation and popups.
When I load page.html in browser(Firefox Lastest), I can see hyper-link test in iframe, but here is the problem: when I click it - nothing appears in console(F12) while following code:

```html
<iframe srcdoc="&lt;script&gt;console.log(1)&lt;/script&gt;" sandbox="allow-scripts || allow-top-navigation || allow-popups"></iframe>
```

Outputs "1" in console.
Why wouldn't the javascript in a href work?

Comment: Also `Error while parsing the 'sandbox' attribute: '||' is an invalid sandbox flag.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You missed some code in your href (`javascript:...`)
- `allow-same-origin`: If this token is not used, the resource is treated as being from a special origin that always fails the same-origin policy. see [MDN doc here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)